# Why does the output always show 0 as LCM?

Tags: c++, lcm

- https://github.com/mehedihasrifat
- Please correct my mistake**
- How can I solve this issue?
- Did I do something wrong here?**

I have been trying to debug this code but ultimately I can't. Please help me, I'm totally new to this platform.

[This picture shows the following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d0pB.png)

```
/*
Written by Mehedi Hasan Rifat
Written on October 2, 2022
*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, t, gcd, lcm;

    printf("Enter two numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

    if (a == 0)
        gcd = b;
    else if (b == 0)
        gcd = a;
    else
    {
        while (b != 0)
        {
            t = b;
            b = a % b;
            a = t;
        }

        gcd = a;
    }

    lcm = (a * b) / gcd;

    printf("LCM: %d\n", lcm);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your final computation of `lcm` needs to use the *original* values of `a` and `b`, NOT the values that have been modified by the loop that calculates `gcd`.  In particular, `b` is guaranteed to be zero when the loop finishes, so your result cannot be anything other than zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [jasonharper says in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper), when you finished the `gcd` calculation, `b` will be always zero.

One quick fix is to add

```
int original_a = a;
int original_b = b;
```

and calculate `lcm` using:

```
lcm = (original_a * original_b) / gcd;
```

Or just use the `__gcd()` function in the `<algorithm>` library.

```
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    ...
    lcm = (a * b) / std::__gcd(a, b);
}
```